# Getting error validation.captcha after form validation

Tags: javascript, laravel, recaptcha

I have explicitly rendered google recaptcha but it is getting validation.captcha error after the form is being validated. I can't find solution for it. I'm doing it in Laravel.

Comment: Please go through [ask].

Answer (score -1):

you can simple use this library: https://github.com/anhskohbo/no-captcha

---

**No Captcha** is a package for implementing Google reCaptcha validation and protecting forms from spamming. First, you need to obtain a free API key from reCaptcha.